# C# List.Add System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

I am handling an event from a child form in its parent form, and when I try adding items from the list contained within the event args of the handler (ScraperForm_SiteScraped in the code below), I am receiving the exception System.InvalidOperationException in my console.

Interestingly enough, it seems to succeed on the first add, but no subsequent attempts.

```
public partial class ProxyTesterView : UserControl
{

    private BindingList<Proxy> proxies = new BindingList<Proxy>();
    private BindingList<ProxyJudge> pudges = new BindingList<ProxyJudge>();
    private BindingList<ProxyTest> tests = new BindingList<ProxyTest>();
    private PauseOrCancelTokenSource pcts = new PauseOrCancelTokenSource();
    private ProxyScraperForm scraperForm = new ProxyScraperForm();

    public ProxyTesterView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        proxies.ListChanged += Proxies_ListChanged;
        scraperForm.SiteScraped += ScraperForm_SiteScraped;
    }

    private void Proxies_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProxiesDataGridView.RowCount = proxies.Count;
    }

    private void AddFromScraperToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scraperForm.Show();
    }

    private void ScraperForm_SiteScraped(object sender, SiteScrapedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var proxy in e.ScrapedProxies)
        {
            proxies.Add(proxy);
        }
    }
}
```

***Child Form***

```
public partial class ProxyScraperForm : Form
{

    private BindingList<IProxyScraperSite> sites = new BindingList<IProxyScraperSite>();

    public int ScrapeInterval { get; set; } = 60000;

    public event EventHandler<SiteScrapedEventArgs> SiteScraped;

    public ProxyScraperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sites.Add(new ProxyScraperSiteUsProxyOrg());
        sites.Add(new ProxyScraperSiteFreeProxyListNet());
        sites.Add(new ProxyScraperSiteFreeProxyListsNet());
        sites.Add(new ProxyScraperSiteHideMyName());
        sites.Add(new ProxyScraperSiteHidester());
        ScraperDataGridView.DataSource = sites;
    }

    private void ScrapeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var site in sites)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var driver = SeleniumUtility.CreateDefaultFirefoxDriver();
                    var newProxies = await site.ScrapeAsync(driver);
                    driver.Quit();
                    OnSiteScraped(newProxies);
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    site.Status = $"Waiting {ScrapeInterval / 1000} seconds...";
                    await Task.Delay(ScrapeInterval);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void OnSiteScraped(List<Proxy> scrapedProxies)
    {
        if (SiteScraped != null)
        {
            SiteScraped(this, new SiteScrapedEventArgs(scrapedProxies));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @eclecticist Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: Is there a message that accompanies the exception?

Comment: @eclecticist Nope.  My IDE doesn't seem to be breaking on it.  But I know the exception is taking place on the line proxies.add(proxy) in the ScraperForm_SiteScraped handler, because I put a break point on that line and it is only executed once, even though e.ScrapedProxies contains more than 1 item.

Comment: Hmm... Could you add a try/catch and put a breakpoint in the catch so that you can examine the exception in more detail?

Comment: @eclecticist Nice tip, that was quite revealing.  Message = "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ProxiesDataGridView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

So I probably need to execute the foreach within ProxiesDataGridView.BeginInvoke

Comment: We need to know the Type of the exception and the exact line it is raised. The Stacktrace may or may not help as well. The message alone is usually the least important part of a Exception. The full Results of a ToString() call help a lot. As you learned just before I finished writing this :)

Comment: @eclecticist Thanks!  Putting the foreach in a BeginInvoke call worked.  I have no idea why my IDE didn't break on it which would have shown me what was really going on, I will search on here for a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our comments, turns out that this was a threading issue. As a good practice, always use a try/catch block when there's a chance that an exception can occur in a block of code. :)

Also, if you're using Visual Studio, you can make VS break on more exceptions by pressing CTRL+ALT+E and selecting the checkboxes. You can read more about exception breaking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/d14azbfh(v=vs.120)).